# texstudio spell check multiple computers

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I'm using `texstudio` on three different computers and use its spell checker.  I regularly have to `ok' words texstudio doesn't recognize and all is well on the computer I'm working on at that time.  But the corrections don't take effect on my other two machines.

The corrections appear to be stored in a file called texstudioen_US.ign in .config/texstudio (on Ubuntu).

Is there a convenient way of forcing texstudio to use a different file, e.g. one stored in Dropbox?  Note: this is the `ignored' file, not the spell check file (/usr/share/hunspell/something in my case) itself.

Comment: I don't know where spelling stuff is stored for TeXStudio, but you can make a symbolic link there to your Dropbox stored version. This is what I do with my local `texmf` folder and some local TeXShop files. See e.g. [TeXShop: Change Stationery location](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/167754).

Comment: put in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to move one version of the file to Dropbox and then put symbolic links to the Dropbox version on each machine:

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/texstudioen_US.ign ~/.config/texstudio/texstudioen_US.ign
```

(Obviously the Dropbox version can be in a more embedded folder as you see fit.)